# Need a bot that should be able to create, write read files and make and execute calls over the network

Tags: java, python

I need a tool/language/course/series which will help me develop a chat bot which will be able to perform various tasks such as read write create files. The bot should be able to make various rest calls, should be able to connect over the internet.

The bot should be able to take parameters from the user and should store and work upon it when needed.

Can you please get me links pointers from where I could start thanks!
Preffered language: Python/Java

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third party interface, a simple to use chat bot structure you can utilize is [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is a framework for building chatbots through the [Discord service](https://discordapp.com/).

You can have your bot running on a machine where it connects to Discord, once it receives commands through the server you may dispatch routines using [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [read/write files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) or [interact with databases](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) (recommended) then reply back accordingly or even attach things.

If you do not wish to use Discord or similar you'll have to develop your own front-end and communication system which is another whole can of worms.